# Exact replace of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, exact-match

```
hidValue="javaScript:java";
replaceStr = "java";
resultStr=hidValue.replace("/\b"+replaceStr+"\b/gi","");
```

resultStr still contains "javaScript:java"

The above code is not replacing the exact string java. But when I change the code and directly pass the value 'java' it's getting replaced correctly i.e

```
hidValue="javaScript:java";
resultStr=hidValue.replace(/\bjava\b/gi,"");
```

resultStr contains "javaScript:"

So how should I pass a variable to replace function such that only the exact match is replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replace-function does not take a string as first argument but a RegExp-object. You may not mix those two up. To create a RexExp-object out of a combined string, use the appropriate constructor:

```
resultStr=hidValue.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+replaceStr+"\\b","gi"),"");
```

Note the double backslashes: You want a backslash in your Regular Expression, but a backslash also serves as escape character in the string, so you'll have to double it.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that in one case you're passing a regular expression literal `/\bjava\b/gi`, and in the other you're passing a string `"/\bjava\b/gi"`. When using a string as the pattern, `String.replace` will look for that *string*, it will not treat the pattern as a regular expression.

If you need to make a regular expression using variables, do it like so:

```
new RegExp("\\b" + replaceStr + "\\b", "gi")
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

`let msisdn = '5093240556699'
let isdnWith = numb.msisdn.slice(8,11);
let msisdnNew = msisdn.replace(isdnWith, 'XXX', 'gi');

show 5093240556XXX`